Godot - optimise multiple instantiation of the same node with different assets
I am building a 2D hex based game. There will be multiple hex types, each with its own behaviour. My implementation so far:
A single 'hex_tile' scene which will provide a sprite and a collision2D nodes: 

A 'HexTile' class which implements shared game logic:
class_name HexTile extends Area2D

@export var hex_type : String = "Unasssinged"
@onready var hex_sprite = $HexSprite
  
func _input_event(viewport: Node, event: InputEvent, shape_idx: int) -> void:
    if event.is_action_pressed("mouse_left_click"):
        print(hexType + " Hex Clicked")

func setPosition(_position: Vector2):
    position = _position

Each hex type is implemented with an inheriting class:
class_name HexTileForest extends HexTile

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    hexType = "Forest"
    super._ready()

A JSON file stores the paths to the assets for each hex type. There are 6 type of hexes (not all shown here):
{
    "hexes": [
        {
            "hex_type_id": "1",
            "name": "Grass",
            "script": "hex_tile_grass.gd",
            "texture": "hex_tile_grass.png"
        },

A configuration class loads the configuration and serves assets:
class_name HexConfiguration extends Node

var hex_data
var hex_textures = []
var hex_scripts = []

func load_hex_config():
    var file = FileAccess.open("res://level/hex_tiles/hex_config.json", FileAccess.READ)
    var json_text = file.get_as_text()
    hex_data = JSON.parse_string(json_text)
    
    for hex in hex_data["hexes"]:
        hex_textures.append(
            [
                hex["hex_type_id"], 
                load("res://level/hex_tiles/" + hex['texture'])
            ]
        )
        hex_scripts.append(
            [
                hex["hex_type_id"], 
                load("res://level/hex_tiles/" + hex['script'])
            ]
        )

func get_hex_script(hex_type_id: String) -> Script:
    for script in hex_scripts:
        if script[0] == hex_type_id:
            return(script[1])
    
    return null

func get_hex_texture(hex_type_id: String) -> Texture:
    for texture in hex_textures:
        if texture[0] == hex_type_id:
            return(texture[1])
    
    return null

func get_hex_name(hex_type_id: String) -> String:
    for hex in hex_data["hexes"]:
        if hex["hex_type_id"] == hex_type_id:
            return(hex['name'])
    
    return ""

A map is an array of integers, each representing a hex_type_id:
[[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7],[7,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,7,7],[7,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,7,7],[7,5,1,3,3,3,6,1,5,5,7,7],[7,7,5,1,1,3,3,6,6,5,7,7],[7,7,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7],[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,5,7],[7,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,6,6,5,7],[7,7,5,1,3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7],[7,5,5,1,3,3,3,6,6,6,5,7],[7,7,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,5,7],[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]]
Finally, the hex_map class loads a map file, and creates the hex map:
class_name HexMap extends Node

# The name of the map file to load
@export var map_name := "map_02.txt"
# Load the vanilla base hex scene
var hex_tile_scene: PackedScene = load("res://level/HexTile.tscn")
# Stores the map array
var map_data = []
# A configuration class
var hex_configuration: HexConfiguration

func _ready():
    # Load the configuration file
    hex_configuration = HexConfiguration.new()
    hex_configuration.load_hex_config()
    # Load the map data
    load_map_data("res://level/maps/" + map_name)
    # Create the map
    create_hex_map()
    
func load_map_data(file_path: String):
    # This loads the map 2D array into map_data, no issues here

func create_hex_map():
    for row_index in range(map_data.size()):
        for column_index in range(map_data[row_index].size()):
            # Fetch the hex_type from map_data
            var hex_type_index = str(map_data[row_index][column_index])
            # Instantiate a new hex tile node
            var new_hex_tile = hex_tile_scene.instantiate()
            # Get the script from hex_configuration and assign to the node
            new_hex_tile.set_script(
            hex_configuration.get_hex_script(hex_type_index))
            # Adding the hex instance to the map
            add_child(new_hex_tile)
            # Set the tile's type name
            new_hex_tile.hex_type = hex_configuration.get_hex_name(hex_type_index)
            # Get the texture from hex_configuration and assign to the node
            new_hex_tile.hex_sprite.texture = hex_configuration.get_hex_texture(hex_type_index)
            # Do some more positioning stuff

This is all working. The issue is that it takes a very long time to load big maps, which is what the game will need.
I had an earlier prototype where each hex type was its own scene with script and texture, however I am planning to add more nodes to the hex node, and don't want to do it again for each type.
How can I optimise this?

This seems like a couple anti-patterns. Try a more Godot friendly approach. Remove HexConfiguration and "hex_config.json" entirely. Replace that with a couple resources. Create a map resource that directly stores the tile resource. The inheritance seems fine, but can be removed by utilizing resources for each unique tile type.

Unrelated to your problem, but have you tried exporting this and running it outside the editor? Using strings that are constructed at runtime to load resources can fail when the project is exported, as resources are packed and no longer on the same path.

@MaxAlexander I did on advice on another forum and you are right that the project is not running so this helps in understanding why. If you have a link to an article or any other related reference that would be great.

It is mentioned in the ResourceLoader documentation for the load() function.
There is an add-on available called Godot Resource Groups that solves this.
